# Jquery Selector match attributes

Tags: jquery, html

I have an interesting case.I am having a jquery selector where I have to select elements based on a fileName.

```
$( "*[fileName='"+filename+"']")
```

CASE A:Linux   OS filenames are generated as /home/username/a.txt
CASE B:Windows OS filenames are generated as c:\programFiles\username\a.txt

CASE A everything works fine
CASE The selector treats the '\' as an escape character so I have to escape them{With a regex or something equivalent}.Here since its single quotes inside double quotes that means I have to escape them twice.

Is there any good way of solving this issue ?

Comment: I will have to escape filename variable which I dont want

Answer (score 0):

```
var filename = filename.replace(/\\/g,'/');
$( "*[fileName='"+filename+"']")
```

Comment: My fileName attribute is windows styled.

Comment: can you please write an example of your expected input filename and expected output file name

Comment: fileName attribute of an element is C:\home\user\a.txt and filename variable is also "C:\home\user\a.txt"
Now I want to select that element

Answer (score 0):

how about this :

```
var filename= encodeURI(filename);
$( "*[fileName='"+decodeURI(filename)+"']")
```